# Standby during playback since iTunes 11

Tags: itunes, imac, appletv

Since I upgraded to iTunes 11, my iMac (27", 2011) goes to sleep during playback to my Apple TV. This didn't happen before the upgrade, so it has to be related to the upgrade. Does anyone what I could do to prevent this from happening? It's kind of annoying. Standard standby time for the iMac is 10 minutes. Thus, after 10 minutes of playback my iMac goes to sleep. Both, my iMac and my Apple TV are running the most up-to-date software.

Comment: That’s a problem. Send feedback to Apple by going to iTunes > Provide iTunes Feedback in the menubar.

Comment: Is the Apple TV pulling content from Home Sharing or is the iMac pushing the sounds over AirPlay? You might try the other if one isn't setting the signal that tells the mac to not sleep since the system is in use. @duci9y is correct - if no one (or not enough people) file bugs at https://bugreporter.apple.com then we will have to wait for Apple to discover and fix that glitch.

Comment: Info: Update 11.0.1 does not fix this issue

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to prevent this from happening right now is to increase your standby time.

The reason it goes to sleep is that iTunes 11 does not set a "power assertion". Here's an Open Radar bug report on this issue: http://openradar.appspot.com/12791690.

Hopefully Apple will change this in an update because I'm having the same annoying problem.

**Update 2012-12-13:** iTunes 11.0.1 just came out and the missing power assertion has returned. Your computer should no longer sleep when streaming to the AppleTV.

Comment: Running itunes 11.1; atv 2; IMac, Still lose connection after 5 to 10 minutes. Power saving settings 3h.

Comment: iTunes 11.0.1 does fix this problem for me. I confirmed that a power assertion gets set with `pmset -g assertions` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. I simply restarted my Apple TV.

Despite the fact, that my problem occured after installing iTunes 11.0.0 (and later 11.0.1 the problem got solved by restating my Apple TV.